# Jquery Ui Accordion Pointer Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, pointer-events

Trying to set it so that the current open section of the Jquery Ui accordion has pointer events set to none, so that I can not click it again. Here is the code I have so far however it is broken.

```
if ($("#accordion h3").hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
    this.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
else {
    this.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}
```

Comment: Is that inside an `on` or `click` event?

Comment: no, should it be? It's just on its own at the moment.

Comment: You would not be able to tell which one is currently open if you do not. The code you have will only run once when it is loaded, unless it is in a function that is called during some other event.